# Finding overlapping dates SQL

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm afraid my question might be rather specific - but I've got a project due soon and I've been struggling writing a proper trigger for an update situation.
I'm currently working with SQL Express.

The sitation is as follows:

Entitities - 
"Employee" (PK Employee_No) can have multiple

"Roles" (PK Role_No, FK Employee_No). This "Role" can be enlisted on various

"Activities" (PK Activity_No, FK Role_No), and the "Activity" can have multiple entries in

"Scheduled work" (PK auto-incremented INT, FK Activity_No, Startdate and Enddate).

Now, to assign an Employee to a Role (via UPDATE on the FK in "Role") - I need to check whether or not this "Employee" is already assigned to another "Role" on which there's "Scheduled work" on days that overlap with the Role to be assigned. If there is, I need to perform a rollback and state what this employee can't be assigned - else assign.

I've tried to work my way around this for quite some time now, but I can't seem to get anything to work - as all my attempts have resulted in the Employee getting assigned anyway OR (as it is now) the UPDATE getting denied even though it shouldn't. Admittedly, I'm fairly new to the SQL Server environment so any hints would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it work just by having a check for the updated -table with exists check for 2x activities and 2x scheduled work?

Comment: a relational table Employee X Date with a unique index ill not let you to put  the same guy to work twice in the same date

Comment: You can do a IF exist with within the After Insert and if the overlap exists raise an error and then rollback the transaction within the trigger.